# execute command telnet via perl script

Tags: perl, telnet

I'm trying to excute a command via a Perl script using telnet, it seem that the script below is able to log in successfully, but can't execute the command. I coudn't find the right regular expression that will wait the prompt `>` before executing the command.

Here is an image of the result when login normaly via telnet:

[image: screenshot]

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Telnet;
my $remote_host = 'myrouter';
my $telnet = new Net::Telnet  (Timeout=>10  ,Input_log => "received_data.txt" );
$telnet->open($remote_host);
$telnet->waitfor('/ADSL2PlusRouter login:/i');
$telnet->print('mylogin'); 
$telnet->waitfor('/Password:/i');
$telnet->print('my_password');
$telnet->waitfor('/-*>/');
$telnet->cmd("adsl show");
$telnet->print('exit');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take into account that there is probably a line break character. I'm not sure how the string that Net::Telnet matches the pattern against looks like exactly, but it's probably enough to add some whitespace into the pattern.

```
$telnet->waitfor('/-\s*>/');
```

This way you will have the last dash of the picture's end line, then maybe some whitespace, which would be a `\n`, followed by the `>`.

Also check out https://regex101.com/r/eQ2pR0/1.

---

**Update**: Going further into the [Net::Telnet documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet#EXAMPLES) I think the first example is pretty useful here. The [docs say this about `prompt`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet#prompt---pattern-to-match-a-prompt).

> This method sets the pattern used to find a prompt in the input stream. It must be a string representing a valid perl pattern match operator. The methods login() and cmd() try to read until matching the prompt. They will fail with a time-out error if the pattern you've chosen doesn't match what the remote side sends.

So I think you don't need to use `waitfor` but instead use `prompt`.

```
$telnet->print('my_password');
$telnet->prompt('/^> /');
$telnet->cmd("adsl show");
```

Because the router doesn't have any information in its prompt, just setting it to 'beginning of string, `>` and a space should work.

Comment: it seem that the pattern is matching but it say command timed-out at telnet.pl line 25 ( refer to that promt regexp ) and the result is : ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> a                                      it's like it's typing the first caracter of the command and it pause

Comment: @sam it sounds like it's not matching. Did you try mine? I'm not familiar with how Net::Telnet works and I don't have a router handy to try.

Comment: it seem to be matching take a look here http://postimg.org/image/63j44gu5t/  it's the first caracter of the cmd "adsl show" this is the print screen of the logout put received_data.txt

Comment: I believe you need to use the `prompt` method. See the first example. https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet#EXAMPLES