# Perl Script to set snmp setting on a router

Tags: perl, router, snmp

I want to telnet to router and set snmp setting ( automated rather than typing it manually)

This is what I do manually:

```
[asafaaya@util-server-1 ~]$ telnet 10.222.24.152
Trying 10.222.24.152...
Connected to 10.222.24.152.
Escape character is '^]'.
Account:admin
Password: *********
Type ? for command help
>mngt snmp -e 1 -g OPTmr9 -s OPTmr9 -t OPTmr9
```

I tried to automate the above but the script is not working as expected. Appreciated if you could check the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Telnet;
use Regexp::Common qw/ net number /;
use Data::Dumper;
my $username = 'admin';
my $password = 'TuR!!!xxx';
my $router = $ARGV[0];
print Dumper $router;
my $t = new Net::Telnet  (Timeout=>10);
$t->open($router);
$t->prompt('/router login:/i');
$t->print($username);
print Dumper $username, "\n";
$t->prompt('/Password:/i');
$t->print($password);
print Dumper $password, "\n";
$t->prompt('/^> /');
$t->cmd("mngt snmp -e 1 -g OPTmr9 -s OPTmr9 -t OPTmr9");
$t->print('exit');
```

Comment: I tried to debugging and not sure why VAR1 variable has different values
[asafaaya@util-server-1 ~]$ ./loginto.pl 10.222.24.152
$VAR1 = '10.222.24.152';
$VAR1 = 'admin';
$VAR2 = '
';
$VAR1 = 'TuR!!!xxx';
$VAR2 = '
';
command timed-out at ./loginto.pl line 22

Comment: What happens if you login something like this - `$t->login($username, $password);` ?

Comment: I hope you did not post your production password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [execute command telnet via perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877134/execute-command-telnet-via-perl-script)

Comment: Perhaps you would be better with [expect](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/exploring-expect/9781565920903/ch01.html) which fits perfectly for such tasks. [Examples](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/), [How to automate tasks with expect](https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/).

Comment: Add to the other answers for using expect. There is also https://metacpan.org/dist/Net-CLI-Interact which is made to interact with routers and switches. However, the best way is to send netconf/restconf commands, this is only avaible on newer devices.

Comment: @ceving no I didn't thanks for your concern

Comment: ./loginto.pl 10.222.xx.xx
$VAR1 = '10.222.xx.xx';
$VAR1 = 'admin';
$VAR2 = '
';
$VAR1 = 'Ur!TY&&';
$VAR2 = '
';
command timed-out at ./loginto.pl line 22

Line 22 is 
$t->cmd("mngt snmp -e 1 -g OPTmr9 -s OPTmr9 -t OPTmr9");

Comment: @vkk05 I get this $VAR1 = '10.222.xx.xx'; Reject the connection request !!! at ./loginto.pl line 16 line 16 is $t->login($username, $password);